# Jagged edged border issue in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I've created a simple CSS play button using borders, which you can see here, using this CSS

```
.btn-play { 
    border-left:50px solid black;
    border-top:40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:40px solid transparent;
}
```

See also: http://jsfiddle.net/o0exn7LL/

This looks fine in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox the edges are jagged. I've seen other issues containing jagged edges in Firefox using 3d transforms, which are solved by adding a transparent outline, but that's not a solution is this case.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get these edges to be more smooth in Firefox?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use images/font icons for that?

Comment: Using CSS keeps me more flexible for using different sizes / colors and animations, and I don't have to load any assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `border-style: inset;`

**CSS**

```
.btn-play { 
  border-left:50px inset black;
  border-top:40px inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom:40px inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/o0exn7LL/3/)**

Comment: Like it, really simple and effective.

Comment: Great solution, thanks! It does however change the color slightly (from black to dark gray, but that's a minor issue)

Comment: @Leon It will not change the color if you use -moz-transform: scale(.9999).

Comment: Yes I noticed that. In this case that's not a huge issue, but I might use the transform solution in the future when the color is a bigger concern. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `-moz-transform: scale(.9999);`

```
.btn-play { 
    border-left:50px solid black;
    border-top:40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:40px solid transparent;
    -moz-transform: scale(.9999); //added this
}
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/o0exn7LL/4/)**

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution! I ended up using the inset border-style solution however. (It seemed simpler as I was already using different transforms for animations on the button)

Answer (score 2):

Add `-moz-transform: scale(.9999);` to your `.btn-play`

```
.btn-play { 
    border-left:50px solid black;
    border-top:40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:40px solid transparent;  
    -moz-transform: scale(.9999);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u4e7t509/)**

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution! I ended up using the inset border-style solution however. (It seemed simpler as I was already using different transforms for animations on the button)

Comment: Wish you all the best :)